# No refactorings available for Typescript files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, refactoring

For some reason, although it's supposed to be bundled into VSCode, I *always* see the message "No refactorings available" when I select some code in a Typescript file and trigger the "Refactor..." command.

This happens both using the hotkey (Ctrl+Shift+R) and using the context menu (right click on selection, choose "Refactor"...).

How could I go about about diagnosing this issue?

Comment: I have the same error you do, but I wanted to point out in case you didn't notice, you can still do certain "refactoring" activities, such as Rename Symbol (F2) to rename a variable.